# blank page when inlcuding lightning component in vf page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I am having a blank page, when calling my app in a visualforce page and i don't know what iam doing wrong.

Here is my component code :

```
  <aura:component controller="newCode">
       <aura:attribute name="Code" type="VMU__SampleCode__c" />

         <!-- new sample code -->
         <div class="slds-col slds-col--padded slds-p-top--large">
           <div class="slds-form--horizontal slds-large-size--1-of-2">
              <form class="slds-form--horizontal">
                   <div class="slds-form-element">                    
                        <ui:inputtext aura:id="title" 
                                       label="Title" 
                                       class="slds-input" 
                                      labelclass="slds-form-element__label" 
                                      value="{!v.Code.VMU__Title__c}"
                                      required="true" />
                  </div>
              </form>
         </div>
     </div>
  </aura:component>
```

Here is my application code :

```
     <aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable">

        <ltng:require styles="{!join(',', $Resource.KB_Resources + '/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css',
                                 $Resource.KB_Resources + '/assets/styles/site.css')}"  />

        <aura:dependency resource="c:storeCode"/>

       <div class="slds"> 
          <c:storeCode />    
      </div>
```

And here is my VF :

```
            <apex:page >
                <apex:includeLightning />
                <div id="lightning" />
                <script>
                    $Lightning.use("c:storeCodeAp", function() {
                      $Lightning.createComponent("c:storeCode",
                      {},
                      "lightning",
                      function(cmp) {
                        // do some stuff
                      });
                    });
                </script>
            </apex:page>
```

I followed the steps required to include an app in the vf as listed, that is :

```
1. Add <apex:includeLightning /> to your Visualforce page
2. Tell your Visualforce page which Lightning app to use
3. Write a function that creates the component on the page
```

I do everything as described. First thing to note is that i have a namespace in my org that is VMU, and when I replace c by this it still doesn't work.

in my page when i inspect and check for javascript error, i have this :

```
     https://vmuknowledgebase-dev-ed--vmu.eu2.visual.force.com/c/storeCodeAp.app?aura.format=JSON&aura.formatAdapter=LIGHTNING_OUT 

     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Are you really sure, that you have replaced all the default namespace `c` with `VMU` in Lightning component and vf page?

Comment: In this example, im not using my namespace but the default one, yet its not working

Comment: Remove the lightning out part and try to test from the dev console. When you open the Aura bundle, it gives you the option to preview the output. At least then you know part of it's working.